# Makefile: Terminates after running commands "go test ./..."

Tags: postgresql, go, testing, makefile

I encountered a problem running "go test" from a makefile. The idea behind all this is to start a docker container, run all tests against it and then stop & remove the container.

The container gets started and the tests run, but the last two commands (docker stop & rm) aren't executed.

Make returns this message:
`make: *** [test] Error 1`

Is it "go test" which terminates the makefile execution?

```
.PHONY: up down test

up:
    docker-compose up

down:
    docker-compose down

test:
    docker run -d \
        --name dev \
        --env-file $${HOME}/go/src/test-api/testdata/dbConfigTest.env \
        -p 5432:5432 \
        -v $${HOME}/go/src/test-api/testdata/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
    
    # runs all tests including integration tests.
    go test ./... --tags=integration -failfast -v
    # stop and remove container
    docker stop `docker ps -aqf "name=dev"`
    docker rm `docker ps -aqf "name=dev"`
```

Comment: Try adding `|| true` to the end of the line to suppress the return code and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: prefix `go test` with a `-` to ignore errors, `-go test`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe That solves my problem. Thank you a lot and have a great weekend!

Comment: @Milag Works too! I will use this solution since the output is more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the 'make test' to return the test status consider the following change to the makefile

```
test:
    docker run -d \
        --name dev \
        --env-file $${HOME}/go/src/test-api/testdata/dbConfigTest.env \
        -p 5432:5432 \
        -v $${HOME}/go/src/test-api/testdata/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres
    
    # runs all tests including integration tests.
    go test ./... --tags=integration -failfast -v ; echo "$$?" > test.result
    # stop and remove container
    docker stop `docker ps -aqf "name=dev"`
    docker rm `docker ps -aqf "name=dev"
    exit $$(cat test.result)
```

It uses the test.result file to capture the exit code from the test